# App engine tasks are not executed in defined target

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am attempting to refactor some of my sites code use modules and no matter what I try, I cannot seem to get the push tasks to execute where I want them.

The basic structure of this piece of the app is like this...

1. User uploads a fairly large and complex XML file to a handler on the default module
2. The handler puts the file in GCS and creates a datastore entry for the file
3. The model has a _post_put_hook that creates two taskqueue jobs that do some processing on this XML file.

I would like the two taskqueue jobs to execute in a instance larger than an F1 as I've been bumping into the soft memory limit of 128MB, and I'd like the jobs to execute a bit faster.

So I created a dispatch.yaml file (which I'm still not quite sure this file is even required) like this...

```
application: myapp
dispatch:
- url: "*/tasks/.*"
  module: tasks
```

And a tasks.yaml like this ...

```
application: myapp
module: tasks
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

instance_class: F2

handlers:
  - url: /.*
  script: tasks.app
  login: admin

libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: "2.3"
- name: ssl
  version: "latest"
```

And finally that post_put_hook that queues the jobs looks like this...

```
def _post_put_hook(self, future):
    if self.identification is None:
        taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/extraction', params={'key': self.key.id()}, target="tasks", name="extractor-%s" % self.key.id())
        taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/indexer', params={'key': self.key.id()}, target="tasks", name="indexer-%s" % self.key.id()))
```

My understanding would be since I've specified a target in the taskqueue() call, it should use the module, but it doesn't. I've tried with and without the dispatch.yaml file deployed to app engine and it seems to make no difference as to where the tasks execute. The app engine dev console seems to acknowledge that there is a tasks module as it offers it as an option for filtering my logs and instance list.

I should add that I deployed the app via the CLI, making sure to specify both my app.yaml and tasks.yaml (that was something that tripped me up for while trying to deploy it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out what the problem was.

I had thought that when using a dispatch.yaml, the "sub" modules (my 'tasks' module) are mounted back at the base url of the respective module ('/*'). I had come to this belief from looking at the example provided here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-helloworld-python where you see

```
- url: "*/mobile/*"
  module: mobile-frontend
```

in the dispatch.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: printenv.APP
```

in mobile_frontend.yaml

and printenv.py mounts the app like...

```
APP = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

I'm still not quite sure how the above code is working, because for my code to work I had to make the adjustment mentioned by Dave above AND...

change my tasks.yaml to be

```
handlers:
- url: /tasks/.*
  script: tasks.app
  login: admin
```

and change the routes in tasks.py look like...

```
ROUTES = (webapp2.Route('/tasks/extraction', ExtractionWorker),
          webapp2.Route('/tasks/indexer', IndexingWorker))
```

previously they looked like

```
ROUTES = (webapp2.Route('/extraction', ExtractionWorker),
          webapp2.Route('/indexer', IndexingWorker))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
- url: "*/tasks/.*"
```

to

```
- url: "*/tasks/*"
```